# ¿cómo agregar más de una coordenada a la vez en una matriz con una sola entrada de datos?

Tags: c++, c

estoy tratando de hacer un battle ship en C o C++ y tengo un problema: no sé cómo hacer que los barcos midan más que un solo punto del tablero. El maestro nos pidió que deben de haber barcos que ocupen 1,2,3 y 4 espacios dentro de un tablero (una matriz), mi problema es que  no hago idea del cómo hacer para que al ingresar yo una ubicación este barco se agregue ocupando el tamaño de barco que haya escogido el jugador.

Comment: Hola. Muéstranos el código de lo que has intentado y pregunta sobre lo que no te funcione. Sin saber cómo estás implementando tu programa es imposible darte una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Es muy fácil: entras datos una vez, agregas coordenadas varias veces.

Comment: Pides al usuario que ingrese la ubicación del barco y después lo agregas en horizontal o vertical según su tamaño, tan fácil como eso.

Answer (score 0):

Con este código puedes ingresar en una sola entrada las coordenadas, cuando lo ejecutes e ingreses las coordenadas, la entrada debe tener el siguiente orden para que funcione: fila columna espacio fila columna espacio fila columna espacio... así sucesivamente, un ejemplo de como tiene que ser: d3 d4 d5 d6 pone el barco en horizontal o bien puede ser b5 c5 d5 e5 pone el barco en vertical, la cantidad de coordenadas ingresadas determinara la longitud del barco, con lo cual, si ingresas a2 (una sola coordenada) el barco tendrá una longitud de uno, si ingresas a2 b2 (dos coordenadas) el barco tendrá una longitud de dos, aclarar que el código solamente se encarga de recibir las coordenadas en una única entrada por medio de un array tipo char y convierte letras y números a valores numéricos tipo int, no crea la matriz ni pone los barcos en la matriz, puedes implementarlo en tu código fuente como una función que puede llamar tu función principal main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//reemplaza letras por el numero correspondiente
char reemplazar(char caracter){
    switch(caracter){
        case 'a':
            return '1';
        case 'b':
            return '2';
        case 'c':
            return '3';
        case 'd':
            return '4';
        case 'e':
            return '5';
        case 'f':
            return '6';
        case 'g':
            return '7';
        case 'h':
            return '8';
        case 'i':
            return '9';
    }

    return caracter;
}

int main(void){
    const int TAM = 17;
    char entrada[TAM];
    char fentrada[TAM];
    int i = 0, j = 0, cantCoo = 1;
    char *token;

    //captura de caracteres en array 'entrada' tipo char
    printf("Ingrese coordenadas: ");
    fgets(entrada,TAM,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    //reemplazar salto de linea por fin de cadena, debido a que se utilizo fgets para captura de caracteres
    while(entrada[i] != '\n') i++;
    entrada[i] = '\0';

    //crear formato que debera tener la secuencia de caracteres ingresados, para que strtok pueda hacer tokens con las comas
    for(i = 0; i < TAM-1; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            fentrada[i] = '-';
        }else{
            fentrada[i] = ',';
        }   
    }

    //aplicar formato, guardando el formato resultante en 'fentrada'
    for(i = 0; entrada[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(entrada[i] != ' '){
            fentrada[j] = entrada[i];
            fentrada[j] = reemplazar(fentrada[j]);
            j+=2;
        }
    }
    fentrada[--j] = '\0';

    //contar cantidad de numeros ingresados
    for(i = 0; fentrada[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(fentrada[i] == ',') cantCoo++;
    }

    //crear array 'coordenadas' de tipo int, de longitud igual a los numeros ingresadas
    int coordenadas[cantCoo];
    i = 0;

    //convertir caracteres a numeros tipo int guardandolo en array 'coordenadas'
    coordenadas[i] = atoi(token = strtok(fentrada,","));
    while(token != NULL){
        coordenadas[++i] = atoi(token = strtok(NULL,","));
    }

    /*
    a partir de aqui las coordenadas estan listas para usar en el tablero
    recordar que en el array los numeros quedan: fila columna fila columna fila columna fila columna
    tal como se muestra recorriendo el array con los valores ya convertidos a int
    */

    for(i = 0; i < cantCoo; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            printf("fila   : %d\n",coordenadas[i]);
        }else{
            printf("columna: %d\n\n",coordenadas[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```